# Would it be possible to utilize Immutable.js in a React-Redux Application for comparing props in shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am currently working on an React-Application where I use Immutable.js in my Redux-Reducers. The reducers will return the previous state as a reference if they have not changed it (as recommended). 
If I now compared the previous state with the next state `(state===nextState)` it would return true, since the reference has not changed, right?

Now if the reducer changed the state, it would return a new Immutable.js Map.

Doing the same comparision now it would return false, since it is a new Map.

Would it be reasonable to somehow detect prop changes within shouldComponentUpdate like that?

If so, is there a way to modify the react-redux connect function to use my custom shouldComponentUpdate method? Because apparently it is not possible to pass an Immutable.js Object as props to a component.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. Please visit the help center and take [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Answer (score 1):

In mapStateToProps, if you are not converting this immutable iterable to equivalent JS object and pass Immutable object as it is. You can do achieve it.

For example:

Instead of

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ ...(state.toJS()) });
```

Way to access any data from state in the component: `this.props.data`

You can also write as:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ state });
```

Way to access any data from state in the component: `this.props.state.get('data')`